# What makes QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::finished() be called?

Tags: android, c++, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using [QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent.html) to search BLE devices on an Android phone.

I request device search to be started by calling [QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::start()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent.html#start). After a few seconds, [QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::finished()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent.html#finished) is emitted, but I did not call [QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::stop()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent.html#stop).

At this point, my BLE device was not found yet (it's slow...I know), and it won't as the system decided on its own to stop the search....so I need to restart the search manually.

Why is the system stopping the search? Qt doc says about [QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::finished()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent.html#finished):

> This signal is emitted when Bluetooth device discovery completes.

What does that mean? How could anyone decide that discovery completes? Does it come from BLE standard? As a end user, I'm the only one who knows when it's completed, i.e. when the device I'm looking for was found....

Comment: That might be forwarded from Android’s bluetooth interface. I’d have a look at the implementation to see what can trigger it.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Good point! `src\bluetooth\qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent_android.cpp`, line 273 they create a 10 seconds timer that will stop scan....You can post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Frank Osterfeld, the android implementation of `QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent` ([see line 273](https://github.com/RSATom/Qt/blob/master/qtconnectivity/src/bluetooth/qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent_android.cpp)) silently creates a 10 seconds timeout that stops the search automatically.

It's a pain for users who want to search for longer than 10sec...

Filled a bug report here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53012